# How to get vocals from song using original song and remix using official vocals

Tags: audio, playback, vocals

There are some songs that have been remixed by the author, so you can assume that at least  some parts of the vocals in both songs are the same. What is the order of operations using a program like Audacity extract the vocal track.

It is similar to this question https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/subtracting-specific-audio-using-an-isolated-track-from-the-same-mix but if you do the subtraction it will result in combining the instrumental part of both songs (I think...) which is not what I want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Let's say I have SUPERELECTROSONG (Remix) and I have SUPERELECTROSONG (Dub Remix) - which is identical to the REMIX version but doesn't have vocals. 
The link you provided has instructions to extract the vocals from the original REMIX using the DUB version.

Comment: I understand that the link is not what I want... It is a similar topic that I thought someone might find useful.

Comment: did my answer help enough?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to say, there is no *perfect* way of doing this. The link you provided uses the same technique I was going to describe but this requires that you have the original and an **exact instrumental copy**. Even that technique is not perfect and will still have some background noise.

**One piece of AWESOME software that does this** with techniques that are far beyond my understanding **is [Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/cms/index.php?id=melodyne).** You can actually isolate many parts of the song with this software. Only downside is the cost and, at least from what I've researched and been told, the isolation isn't *perfect*. My experience with this program is quite low since I just obtained it so there is more than likely a way to decrease the amount of background noise that comes when you isolate a sound. Melodyne is also great for fixing pitch in recorded vocals and is the reason I got it.

**Of course the best way is to use the technique you already discovered or just asking the artist(s) for the isolated vocal track ^_^**

Comment: +1 for asking the artist. There is a strong community around sharing stems or entire parts.

Comment: totally! [acapellas4u](http://www.acapellas4u.co.uk/) is a pretty awesome site for finding people who want to share stems and vocals. Just asking people that I followed or vice versa on soundcloud had the same results ^_^